# Generation of hash key

Tags: android, facebook

When I am going to generate hash key for facebook integration. I have got this error.

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1>keytool -exportcert -alias
>   androiddebugkey -keys tore "C:\Users\MEGHA.android\debug.keystore" |
>   "C:\openssl\bin\openssl" sha1 -b inary |
>   "PATH_TO_OPENSSL_LIBRARY\bin\openssl" base64 'keytool' is not
>   recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or
>   batch file.

Please tell me where I am wrong. Please give me the right solution for this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Install "keytool""

Comment: Check directory if keytool executable exists or not.

Comment: In which directory I can find keytool executable @ADM

Comment: yes keytool exists

Comment: The directory in error C:\Program Files\Java\....

Comment: Thankyou so much. I got it where I did mistake

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Just select gradle from left side and you will see option for signing report. Click on signing report in the below you will get debug hash key.

Answer (score 1):

Use this for generate hash key

```
public void printHashKey() {
    // Add code to print out the key hash
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.Bhomeo",
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.e("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), 
    Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```